# GroupJoin and Include

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, include, grouping

After GroupJoin i want to include Book.Authors, because field Book.Authors will be null.
But i can't. What should i do to solve this?

```
Queryable<NewRead> recent = Repository.NewReads.Where(x => x.UserId == usersId);

var newFavs = IsAuthorized ? Repository.NewFavs.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId) : Repository.NewFavs.Where(x => false);

var recentFavorite = recent.GroupJoin(newFavs,
                             x => x.BookId,
                             y => y.BookId,
                             (x, y) => new {Recent = x, Favorite = y, x.Book});
```

I tried:

```
var recent = Repository.NewReads.Include("Book.Authors")
                   .Where(x => x.UserId == usersId);
```

and

```
var newFavs = IsAuthorized ? Repository.NewFavs.Include("Book.Authors").Where(x => x.UserId == UserId) : Repository.NewFavs.Where(x => false);
```

and all this together.
It worked before GroupJoin, but after Authors field looses.
If i add:

```
var recentFavorite = recent.GroupJoin(newFavs,
                             x => x.BookId,
                             y => y.BookId,
                             (x, y) => new {Recent = x, Favorite = y, x.Book, x.Book.Authors});
```

All works fine, but it isn't solution.

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities? Something else?

Comment: Many people tell that after grouping shape changes and all includes ignore.

Comment: Linq to sql i think. Because uses repository, but not DBContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var recent = Repository.NewReads.Include(x => x.Book.Authors)
                       .Where(x => x.UserId == usersId);
```

Comment: I tried:var recent = Repository.NewReads.Include("Books.Authors")
                       .Where(x => x.UserId == usersId);

Comment: Are you using linq to sql? "Include" in the title suggests entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
var recent = Repository.NewReads.Include("Book").Where(n => n.UserId == usersId).FirstOrDefault().Book.Select(b=>b.Authors);
```

Comment: .Book.Select(b=>b.Authors); Book is field(not queryable) how can we do select? And i think it won't help because i tried something similar. But after GroupJoin all Include looses.

Comment: Could you please explain more about your relations between tables in database and even your models?

Comment: Yeah, there are NewFav, NewReads, Books, Users, Authors tables. NewFav, NewReads link to Book (column BookID), Authors have column BookID too. And NewFav and NewReads have  UserID column.

Comment: So i need Book and all Authors. Without GroupJoin all works fine, if i write Include("Book.Authors"). For example if i i take first in "recent" query, it has book and not null authors. But after GroupJoin authors are null.